# Past simple vs continuous m

Tags: past-continuous

I have studied a lot about the past simple and continuous. I know that we use the past simple when we state a fact and that the continuous is used to create the background. My question is I hear that people say "what did you do yesterday" and not "what were you doing yesterday"
Therefore, I get that it is more natural to use the past simple. Does is always work like that with other expressions like: last week last year on your holiday?

Is is natural to say what were you doing on your holiday since we ask about something temporary and if the answer is " yes" why it is not natural to ask "what were you doing yesterda"?

Comment: Forget about the temporary thing. Simple past is final and over. Continuous is about a certain activity that lasts a certain time in the past. It's not about more or less natural. It's about what **you mean**. "What were you doing all day yesterday because you certainly did not do your chores".

Comment: What if I just say yesterday without all day?

Comment: It's not about grammar.

Comment: The continuous tense isn't necessarily about 'creating the background', though it can be (_The sun was shining_). It can be about 'how someone spent a particular period of time' (_I was playing tennis all afternoon_) or what they were doing when something else happened (_I was having dinner when the phone rang_).

Comment: What were you doing yedterday? I was playing, reading and cooking. What did you do yesterday. I played read and cooked. Are both versions correct and natural. The only difference I can see is that continuoud implies that things happened at the same time and simplr one after another?